# php escaping when I don't need it to

Tags: php, escaping

I've got an issue whereby PHP is escaping where I really don't want it to in this code:

```
        $url_ = stripslashes(((substr(strtolower($url),0,7)!="http://")? "http://".$url:$url));
        $host = $this->googleDomains[mt_rand(0,count($this->googleDomains)-1)];
        $target = "/search?";
        $querystring = sprintf("client=navclient-auto&ch=%s&features=Rank&q=%s",
            $this->CheckHash($this->HashURL($url_)),urlencode("info:".$url_));
        $contents="";

        $this->debugRes("host", $host);
        $this->debugRes("query_string", $querystring);
        $this->debugRes("user_agent", $this->userAgent);
```

thus producing a URL like this which causes the script to fail:

```
{"urls":[{"url":"hostcule.com","converted_url":"http:\/\/toolbarqueries.google.com\/search??client=navclient-auto&ch=74451333464&features=Rank&q=info%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fhostcule.com"}]}
```

How do I stop it?

Magic Quotes are Off.

Here's the $url comes from:

```
foreach (preg_split('#[\r\n]+#', $_POST['urls']) as $url) {
        $url = trim($url);
        if ($url)
            $_SESSION['converted_urls'][] = array('url' => $url, 'converted_url' => $pr->GetPR($url, true, true));
    }
```

At this stage, $_POST['urls'] looks like:

```
{"urls":[{"url":"hostcule.com","converted_url":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/search??client=navclient-auto&ch=74451333464&features=Rank&q=info%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fhostcule.com"}]}
```

whilst $url looks like

```
 {"urls":[{"url":"hostcule.com","converted_url":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/search??client=navclient-auto&ch=74451333464&features=Rank&q=info%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fhostcule.com"}]}
```

Comment: Where is the escaped output appearing? This one line isn't enough to show the problem case.

Comment: We need more code to see where `$url` is being malformed, feed us code!

Comment: your wish is my command guys :)

Comment: No no no, *up* the creek! Where does `$url` come from? 2 beers that the error is already in it.

Comment: What does $url look like at that stage? What does $_POST["urls"] look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in that code that would produce the code you quote.

My suspicion is that `$url` already contains the garbled `http\/\/`, and therefore your http:// recognizing mechanism never triggers.

You need to step back and look where `$url` comes from. There is where your problem will be.

Comment: would
preg_split('#[\r\n]+#', $_POST['urls'])
trip it?
Yes it would? but then why?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have there doesn't do any escaping at all. You'll need to post what you do to that $url_ after this line.

Answer (score 0):

use ' instead of "

Comment: This won't make the slightest difference.